# Swift - issue calling function in obj c

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

In my project I'm using objective c in my swift project but when I try to call swift function.

I have this Xcode error:

```
Fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value*
```

Those objects exist, but sees them as `nil`. I can't understand the reason.

**share.m**

```
 @interface ViewControllerDio () <UIAlertViewDelegate>

@end
@implementation ViewControllerDio
 - (void)prova:(ShareViewController *) shareviewcontroller {

  [shareviewcontroller abilitaOggetti];

 }
```

**ShareViewController.swift**

```
var name: String?
init(name: String) {

    self.name = name
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil);
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder){
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

class func newInstanceNamed(name: String) -> ShareViewController {
    return ShareViewController(name: name)
}

func abilitaOggetti(){


    println("working")
}

   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
 @IBAction func share(){

       var start: ViewControllerDio = ViewControllerDio()
    //    start.share(image)

        start.prova(start)


    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outlets are only filled in as the view controller's view loads.  Since you haven't done anything with the view controller that would require a view (i.e. pushed or presented it) by the time you call `abilitaOggetti`, I wouldn't expect the sub-views to be instantiated yet.

Put a breakpoint in the swift function to verify the values.

Comment: Sorry, I don't speak english very well. I can't understand, can you write an example?

Comment: It's hard to give an example because that depends on how you intend to use `viewController`.  I assume you want to show the controller's view at some point using either `presentViewController` or `pushViewController`.  What I'm saying is that you need to show it before using the outlets.

Comment: I work with Swift language. I need to use obj c because there are more doc to use fb SDK. In my project I share an image with objc and I pass image with swift. But I want call swift function in objc because I don't know if the image is uploaded or not. See my edit code.

Comment: This isn't really a Swift/Objective-C problem.  Note that when you call `newInstanceNamed`, it creates a **new instance**.  Do you understand that the `ViewController` object that calls `start.share()` is not the same `ViewController` object you're using when you call `abilitaOggetti` because `newInstanceNamed ` created a different one?

Comment: Change `- (void)share{` to `- (void)share:(ViewController *) viewcontroller {`, remove `ViewController * viewcontroller = [ViewController newInstanceNamed:@"istanza"];`, and pass `start` to the Objective-C `share` method?

Comment: 2015-01-02 16:02:23.653 HiStatus[8520:814002] -[ViewControllerDio abilitaOggetti]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x78e3a220
2015-01-02 16:02:23.657 HiStatus[8520:814002] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ViewControllerDio abilitaOggetti]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x78e3a220'

Comment: Sorry.  Pass the object that implements `abilitaOggetti` (`self`) to the method that calls `abilitaOggetti`.

Comment: can you edit my question with the right code? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the nibName to the filename of your nib:

```
super.init( nibName: "ViewController", bundle: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

[@PhillipMills](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27743042/1298400) has the right answer, but let me explain in a different way.

`bottone`, `punti`, `casella`, `immagine` are `nil` until the view is loaded.

In the Objective C sample you have above, you call `-abilitaOggetti` after the instance has been created, but before the view is loaded.

The simple solution is to remove the call to `-abilitaOggetti` in the Objective C and add it to `ViewController`'s `func viewDidLoad()`.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.abilitaOggetti()
}
```

Here is a more complex solution which allows you to keep the Objective C code. It tests if the view has been loaded before doing the work in `-abilitaOggetti`.

```
var needsAbilitaOggettiOnViewDidLoad: Bool

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if (self.needsAbilitaOggettiOnViewDidLoad) {
        self.needsAbilitaOggettiOnViewDidLoad = false
        self.privateAbilitaOggetti()
    }
}

private func privateAbilitaOggetti() {
    self.bottone.hidden = false  //HERE*
    self.punti.hidden = false //HERE*
    self.casella.hidden = false //HERE*
    self.immagine.hidden = false //HERE*
}

func abilitaOggetti() {
    if (self.isViewLoaded()) {
        self.privateAbilitaOggetti()
    } else {
        self.needsAbilitaOggettiOnViewDidLoad = true
    }
}
```

Comment: I've just put some edit to my question ( in the code ). @Jeffery Thomas